# Text field to array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, textbox

I am trying to create an array from a text field. I need to paste fifty lines into a text field. Then convert the lines to an array, with each line being a different element in the array.

Comment: [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) would probably help.

Comment: posting code you tried would probably help too

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I don't know what to google to even start this. However, this is similar to what I am trying to do... http://function.me/?page=1               Though I want my text field to export all the strings in to an array

Comment: what are you trying to make? Can you provide some context?

Comment: I am trying to make a text field to input fifty domains (copy/paste) in to at a time. Then have it parse them in to an array so I can integrate with the moz api. To check SEO value.

Comment: In its current form, your question is too ambiguous to answer and will probably be [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). You need to be more specific. For starters, many languages have text fields. Which one are you using? [Ask].

Answer (score 2):

Given an input field like this:

```
<textarea id="myInput"></textarea>
```

You can get the value from the text field as follows:

```
var myValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
```

And then split it like this

```
var myArray = myValue.split("\n");
```